# Object oriented design for a vehicle configuration kiosk from an interview

Tags: oop

I had an interview question that asked how I would design a system to show cars/trucks/vans at a kiosk so customers could look at specs on the vehicles. (Warning: I have not done much OO programming lately so bad vocabulary may follow)

I said I was start with a class, vehicle that had very basic properties like wheelbase, drive train, hp. Then I would subclass that into  car, truck or van where I could have more specfic measurements like bed length for trucks or trunk capacity for cars.

Then they asked, how would I add options. I said that options could probably exist on any vehicle so I would say that a vehicle could have a list of options.

Finally they asked, what if there was an option that was only available on trucks and vans but not cars and I was a little stumped. Is there some way to make this nicely happen given the layout I described? Is there a better way to set up the class hierarchy to solve this? Or is this just a more complex problem that cant easily be solved without adding some extra logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options for that scenario.

First, the easy one:

**Option #1 - Interface for Trucks/Vans**

If only trucks and vans implement Options, then create an interface called IVehicleOptions and have trucks and vans implement it:

```
public interface VehicleOptions
{
  Options { get; }
}
```

The drawback to this is that now you have to treat cars differently than trucks and vans.

**Option #2 - Null Design Pattern**

However, you can use the **Null Design Pattern**. Have Car implement IVehicleOptions, and just return null:

```
public class Car : IVehicleOptions
{
  public VehicleOptions { get { return null; } }
}
```

**Option #3 - Strategy Pattern**

Create a base class, like Vehicle:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
  public Options Options { get; protected set; }
}
```

And have each concrete class set it:

```
public class Car : Vehicle
{
  public Car()
  {
    this.Options = NullOptions();  // This is the null design pattern used with this strategy pattern
  }
}

public class Truck : Vehicle
{
  public Truck
  {
    this.Options = SuperOptions();
  }
}

public class Van: Vehicle
{
  public Van
  {
    this.Options = ElegantOptions();
  }
}
```

Now all vehicles can be treated the same way (as a Vehicle).

Answer (score 2):

1* make `Vehicle` abstract so that it has to be extended as in `Class Car extends Vehicle`.

2* all the abstract methods must be implemented by all the concrete children, but all the methods need be abstract. So use partial implementation.

3* So in the case where you need an option for classes `Truck` and `Van` but not `Car`, create an implemented method in `Vehicle`. Since it's implemented, any children has the choice (or not) of overriding it.

4* you may also use interfaces. `Truck` and `Van` may share an interface that `Car` need not share.

Since it's been a while for you, you should review: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

Since Van and Truck have extra feature which car do not have and we cant add that feature in the common interface, I think of segregating the interface which is one of the SOLID principle wherein van and truck would implement another interface which extends the basic interface. Mean to say:-

```
Interface IVehicle{
void move();
} 
Interface IVehicleExtra extends IVehicle{
// Have methods for extra features for Van and Truck
void limitSpeedEighty();
}
class Car implements IVehicle{
void move(){
}
}
class Van implements IVehicleExtra{
void move(){
}
void limitSpeedEighty(){
}
}
class Truck implements IVehicleExtra{
void move(){
}
void limitSpeedEighty(){
}
}
```

I hope my understanding and presentation is clear.